# Javascript error: Python routine to log into a website

Tags: javascript, python

I have been trying to get into a website and fetch some data using python. But I am facing an error when I run my script. Here I am trying to just log in to the website and print the entire website text. Script and error are as below:

Script:

```
import requests

with requests.session() as s:
    proxy_url = "http://{0}:{1}@proxy.blah.blah.com:8099".format('user_id', 'Password')
    s.proxies = {'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url}

    user_id_url = "https://example.ex.com/my.policy"
    Headers = {'Host': 'example.ex.com', 'Connection': 'keep-alive','Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1822238803.1429212674; LastMRH_Session=0a0d8c67; MRHSession=ded054e0afe1bb151c3d35cb0a0d8c67; TIN=273000', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'}
    data = data = {'username': 'website_uid', 'password': 'website_password'}
    r= s.post(user_id_url, data = data, headers = Headers)
    print r.status_code
    print r.text
```

Error:

```
<script language="javascript">
setDefaultLang();
</script><noscript>
<div id="noscript_warning_red">JavaScript is not enabled. Please enable JavaScript in your browser or contact your system administrator for assistance.</div>
<div id="noscript_warning_newsession">To open a new session, please  <A href="/">click here.</A></div>
</noscript>
```

PS: I am able to print the html text of the page, but I am not able to login correctly and hence displaying the error output.

Javascript is enabled in my browser, I double checked it even while posting this question

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Suggestion: try logging in manually first and logging the interaction in an app like Fiddler or the browser's network log. I guess `setDefaultLang()` will redirect to a language specific URL e.g. `/en/my.policy`.

Comment: I tried to look for setDefaultLang() with the help of chrome dev tools, but I am not able to find it under the network tab!! Am I looking at the right place? Can you give me more details on this @lmz

Comment: I can't give you more details... only you can get more details for your specific site. Seriously. Try capturing all browser traffic using e.g. fiddler to see. Try starting at the beginning (GET the form page first) before you POST the login.